# How to navigate to a child component in Angular 9

Tags: firebase, routes, angular9

I am using Firebase to authenticate users. After following the tutorial on techiediaries (https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-firebase/angular-9-firebase-authentication-email-google-and-password/) an issue persists where the user logs in but they won't be sent to the addblog page. This is the error that I get:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'editor-space/addblogs'
> Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'editor-space/addblogs'

I defined the parent route (I guess is the term) as directing to AdminComponent which just displays routing-outlet, and a child route is directed towards AddBlogsComponent.

LoginComponent

```
import {FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../services/auth/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form = new FormGroup({
    email: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
    password: new FormControl('', [Validators.required])
  });

  constructor(private FB: FormBuilder,
              private router: Router,
              private authService: AuthService
  ) {}
  login() {
    console.log('Hello');
    this.authService.login(this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['editor-space/addblog']);
    }
  }

}
```

AuthService

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { auth } from 'firebase/app';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { User } from 'firebase';
import { MylocalStorageService } from '../localStorage/mylocal-storage.service';
import {async} from '@angular/core/testing';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
  user: User;

  constructor(
      private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
      private router: Router,
      private myLocalStorageService: MylocalStorageService
  ) {
    afAuth.authState.subscribe(user => {
      if (user) {
        this.user = user;
        myLocalStorageService.storeData('user', this.user);
      } else {
        myLocalStorageService.storeData('user', null);
      }
    });
  }

  async login(email: string, password: string) {
    console.log(email);
    console.log(password);
    const result = await this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    await this.router.navigate(['editor-space/addblogs']); // This doesn't work
  }
```

Admin-routing.module

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { VerifyEmailComponent } from './verify-email/verify-email.component';
import { AddBlogComponent } from './add-blog/add-blog.component';
import {AdminComponent} from './admin/admin.component';
import {AngularFireAuthGuard} from '@angular/fire/auth-guard';

const  routes: Routes  = [
    { path:  'editor-space', component: AdminComponent,
        children: [
            { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
            { path: 'addblog', component:  AddBlogComponent },
            { path: 'forgot_password', component:  ForgotPasswordComponent },
            { path: 'register', component:  RegisterComponent },
            { path: 'verify_email', component: VerifyEmailComponent },
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
        ]
    }
];
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export  class  AdminRoutingModule { }
```

But if you refresh the page you will be directed to the page.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to navigate to 'editor-space/addblogs' in Auth service, but the correct path that is defined in Admin-routing is 'addblog'.